# Node Red to IBM Cloud

Tags: ibm-cloud, node-red

I am new to this forum, so hello to everybody.
I am trying to use the Node Red in IBM Cloud. Let me specify, I have a Lite account on the platform but currently no app installed.
I tried starting the Deploy to IBM Cloud function but once the Delivery pipeline is started, after some some second (approximately 30) the following error is shown.
...
Updating app node-red-app-20201213104801716...
Mapping routes...
Comparing local files to remote cache...
Packaging files to upload...
Uploading files...

0 B / 52.67 KiB 0.00%
52.67 KiB / 52.67 KiB 100.00%
52.67 KiB / 52.67 KiB 100.00%
52.67 KiB / 52.67 KiB 100.00%
52.67 KiB / 52.67 KiB 100.00%
52.67 KiB / 52.67 KiB 100.00%
52.67 KiB / 52.67 KiB 100.00%
52.67 KiB / 52.67 KiB 100.00% 1s

Waiting for API to complete processing files...

Staging app and tracing logs...
FAILED
You have exceeded your organization's memory limit: app requested more memory than available

Finished: FAILED
.....

I saw somebody around got a similar error but in case other app was running (which is not the case here). In addition I do not see any specific error code details to look over for a possible more specific solution.
Do you have some hints how which could be the cause and how to solve it?

Any advice much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I think the max size you should set the slider to is 128mb.